# Values not being calculated or accumlated correctly?

Tags: java

```
-omitted code-

{
while(miles != -999)
                    {
        System.out.print("Enter the numbers of gallons purchased: ");
        gallons = input.nextDouble();

        totalmpg = (totalmiles / totalgallons);
        totalgallons = totalgallons + gallons;

        System.out.printf("Your miles per gallon this tank was:%.2f\n ", mpgthistank);
                    mpgthistank = miles / gallons;

        System.out.printf("Your total miles driven is:%.2f\n ", totalmiles);
                    totalmiles = totalmiles + miles;

        System.out.printf("Your total gallons used is:%.2f\n: ", totalgallons);
                    totalgallons = totalgallons + gallons;

        System.out.printf("Your total miles per gallon is:%.2f\n ", totalmpg);
                    totalmpg = totalmiles / totalgallons;

                    System.out.print("Enter the number of miles traveled<-999 to quit>: ");
        miles = input.nextDouble();
        }
```

Not entirely sure why. This is the run I get:

```
Enter miles driven since last full tank <-999 to quit>: 100

Enter the numbers of gallons purchased: 10

Your miles per gallon this tank was:0.00

Your total miles driven is:0.00

Your total gallons used is:10.00

Your total miles per gallon is:NaN

Enter the number of miles traveled<-999 to quit>:

But it should read:

Your miles per gallon this tank was: 10

Your total gallons used is: 10

Your total miles per gallon is: 10
```

... and then the loop should start over (which it does). I am sure it is a simple syntax error, but I cannot put my finger on the error.

Comment: You aren't performing the calculation until after you print it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this:

```
System.out.printf("Your miles per gallon this tank was:%.2f\n ", mpgthistank);
mpgthistank = miles / gallons;
```

First you are printing the value, and then you calculate it.

Reverse the statements - first calculate the value, then print it.

```
mpgthistank = miles / gallons;
System.out.printf("Your miles per gallon this tank was:%.2f\n ", mpgthistank);
```

Comment: Thank you Jesper. Been stuck on that for about 2 hours now. Much ablige.

Comment: @Monteezy If you has used a debugger, you would have found it in seconds.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use a debugger in my programming class, Peter.

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating the results for your variables AFTER you are printing them. Of course it doesn't work. Just move print statements after the actual calculations.

Secondly, you are doing some calculations twice which doesn't make sense. Also keep in mind you'll need to update some variables to zero, depending on what you want. If you want to calculate everything every time independently, `totalgallons = totalgallons + gallons` will be aggregating gallons for each loop pass... which could be what you really want, but may be not.

Answer (score 1):

The NaN result on the first pass is likely because `totalgallons` is still 0.  Since we can't divide by zero, the result is Not a Number (NaN).

Due to the order of your arithmetic, the values being displayed on each iteration are not using the values inputted on that iteration.  For example, `totalmiles` should include the `miles` just gotten from `input`.

Your logic should look something like this:

```
// Get input ...

// Do arithmetic
totalmiles += miles;
totalgallons += gallons;            

mpgthistank = miles / gallons;
totalmpg = totalmiles / totalgallons;

// Print output ...
```

In addition to being correct, this is a cleaner way to write the sample code.  If you're not familiar with `+=`, `totalmiles += miles` is shorthand for `totalmiles = totalmiles + miles`